# Can I only get the div of a html source code with Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm creating an application that will take the div of this page https://gyp.ch/ecran/ to show it.

I tried to find a way to getElementByID with Kotlin but I don't think it's possible because of JVM.

```java
logo.setOnClickListener {
 "https://gyp.ch/ecran/".httpGet().responseString{request,response,result ->
  profs.text = result.get()
 }
}

It just displays the result.get() so in this case the code source of the link above.
```

Comment: You'll need to find a parsing library for html.  Html parsing isn't built into the framework, because Android doesn't use HTML natively at all, so getElementById is pointless.  And really, if you're trying to parse it for information I'd HIGHLY recommend against it-  minor changes in the source of the page will break your code constantly.  If you own that page, you should write a webservice to send you the data instead.  If you don't, you should find an alternative source

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using kotlin you can easily add `jsoup` to your project.

`implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'`

simple example -

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://gyp.ch/ecran/").get();
log(doc.title());
Elements allDivs = doc. getElementsByTag("div");
for (Element div : allDivs) {
 div.text()
}
```

Comment: Friendly reminder that `compile` is deprecated and scheduled for removal (although I'm pretty sure it has been removed by now)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @zoe, i'll take care of it in future.